# Can we use TF-lite to do retrain?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization-aware-training

I converted a pretrained model to TF-lite and would like to deploy to the edge device.
If we got new training data and would like to improve the pretrained model, is it possible to do on the edge device?
Ex. Is there any method to train the model and save to TF-lite(FlatBuffer) again on edge device?

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: You can retrain the model using frozen graphs and TFLite models. If you get new training data and want to update the model in your app, try hosting it using Firebase MLKit. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/use-custom-models).

Comment: Hi @ShubhamPanchal 
I read Firebase MLKit:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models

It looks like to train\customize the model through Firebase and Cloud AI, not directly train on device? Please help correct me if I misunderstand it. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-device training is not fully supported yet on TF Lite but you can refer to this blog post to see how it can be done.
https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/12/example-on-device-model-personalization.html

The basic idea is:

- Split your model to a base subgraph (e.g. feature extractor in an image classification model) and a trainable head.
- Convert the base subgraph to TF Lite as normal. Convert the trainable head to TF Lite using the experimental tflite-transfer-convert tool.
- Retrain the trainable head on-device as you wish.